# Nodejs + CoffeeScript + Mongoose : Define Module?

Tags: node.js, coffeescript, mongoose

I'm trying to create a little application to store snippets of code using nodejs and mongodb 
I'm using Coffeescript to write the app.

The problem is, i want to separate the code in modules
so i create this folder structure

```
/app
    /lib
        /models
        /routes
    core.coffee
```

The core.coffe is the "server" app using expressjs
so in this file i have

```
mongoose = module.exports.mongoose = require 'mongoose'
app      = module.exports.app   = express.createServer()
Snippet  = module.exports.Snippet = require __dirname+'/lib/models/Snippet'
#App configurations
routes  = require(__dirname+'/lib/routes/general')
```

In lib/models/Snippet

```
mongoose = module.parent.exports.mongoose
Snippet = new mongoose.Schema
    title:
        type: String
        default:'Title'

mongoose.model 'Snippet',Snippet
exports.Snippet = mongoose.model 'Snippet'
```

In /lib/routes/general.coffee

```
app      = module.parent.exports.app
mongoose = module.parent.exports.mongoose
Snippet  = module.parent.exports.Snippet

app.get '/test', (req,res)->
    snip = new Snippet()
    res.send snip
```

But this don't work i get the following error message

```
TypeError: object is not a function
at Object.CALL_NON_FUNCTION_AS_CONSTRUCTOR (native)
```

How can I accomplish that?

Comment: Where are you getting the `TypeError`? On `snip = new Snippet()`?

Comment: Have you checked that `require __dirname+'/lib/models/Snippet'` is returning a function in `core.coffee`?

Answer (score 0):

I see a noteworthy typo:

```
Snippet  = module.exports.Snippt = require __dirname+'/lib/models/Snippet'
```

Change `module.exports.Snippt` to `module.exports.Snippet`.

Comment: was a typo here.. .. i fix that

Answer (score 0):

Let's start by looking at how you're using require. It looks like you're trying to load all the project's requirements in core.coffee, and then re-export them elsewhere. That's an odd way of doing it, most people just `require` those libraries in each module that needs them (for now at least, see the end of my answer).

For example, you need mongoose in lib/models/Snippet, so just require it there:

lib/models/Snippet:

```
mongoose = require 'mongoose'
```

Next, there's no need to use `__dirname` to require a relative path, require copes fine with a path starting with `./`:

```
require './lib/models/Snippet'
```

I still wasn't able to get the code to work cleanly (I'm guessing we're not seeing the full code), but it might be enough to set you on the right path.

---

Finally, if you want to go down the route of exporting everything on the main module can I suggest taking a look at dave-elkan's layers project. The plain version doesn't support coffeescript, but I've created a [fork](https://github.com/mcclade/layers) that does.

It's very lightweight, and makes almost no assumptions about your project structure. The basic idea is that you give `layers()` your express app object and a directory. Layers will scan that directory and set up any subdirectories as layers on your app object.

In your case you'd pass in a `rootPath: __dirname + '/lib'` and your app object would get `app.models.Snippet` and `app.routes.general` added onto it. That's still not quite how I'd structure it, but you might be able to come up with something that matches your style from there.